# Rails 4: :has_many, :through and table names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running Rails 4 here. I just spent 2 hours trying to figure this out to no avail. Would someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Step 1: Create Migration

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableCommandContact command contact
```

Ste 2: Edit migration to add an additional `notification_type` column.

```
class CreateJoinTableCommandContact < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :commands, :contacts, :id => false do |t|
      t.index [:contact_id, :command_id]
      t.string "notification_type", :null => false
    end
  end
end
```

This results in a table names `commands_contacts` (both plural)

Step 3: Create models

command.rb

```
class Command < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :command_contacts
  has_many :contacts, :through => :command_contacts

end
```

contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :command_contacts

    has_many :host_commands, -> { where notification_type: 'host' }, class_name: 'CommandContact'
    has_many :host_notification_commands, :through => :host_commands, class_name: 'Command', :source => :command

    has_many :service_commands, -> { where notification_type: 'service' }, class_name: 'CommandContact'
    has_many :service_notification_commands, :through => :service_commands, class_name: 'Command', :source => :command

end
```

commands_contacts.rb join model

```
class CommandContact < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :command
    belongs_to :contact

end
```

Step 4: Test it.

```
irb(main):001:0> Contact.first.host_notification_commands
```

Which results in following error

```
  Contact Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `contacts`.* FROM `contacts`  ORDER BY `contacts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Mysql2::Error: Table 'ngconf_development.command_contacts' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `command_contacts`
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'ngconf_development.command_contacts' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `command_contacts`
```

I have tried using every imaginable combination of command(s) and contact(s) in my migration and models, but still can't get this to work. What am i doing wrong here?

Why is it trying to use command_contacts with command in singular form?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `has_and_belongs_to_many`? :)

Comment: @H-man: Yes, sir. I need to have additional `:notification_type` attribute on the commands_contacts join table and that is not possible with `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm assuming you ran `db:migrate` since you say:

> This results in a table names commands_contacts (both plural)

Now, your error is clearly saying it's looking for a table named `command_contacts` (note that command is **not plural**) and can't find it. Therefore I assume the problem is that you defined the association wrong inside your models.

Try changing the `has_many` command in `Command` to:

`has_many :commands_contacts`

and in `Contact` to:

`has_many :commands_contacts`

Comment: Aaaand you solved it. I've actually trie everything plural before, except the actual join model class name! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options:

a) Rename table `commands_contacts` to `command_contacts`, or

b) Rename the relation on both sides to `has_many :commands_contacts` and the join model to `CommandsContact`, or

c) I'm not sure if this will work, but I remember being able to do this. Keep the current db setup and use `has_and_belongs_to_many` in the block format. i.e:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :commands do
    def service
      where(notification_type: 'service')
    end
  end
end
# contact.commands.service
```